# foreach loop odd behavior

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I'm getting odd behavior (it generates only missing values) from the following loop -

```
foreach x of varlist name {   
    egen totalcap`x' = total(cap) if unit!=0 & name=="`x'", by(year)   
}
```

But if I were to do just

```
egen totalcapSOMENAME=total(cap) if unit!=0 & name=="SOMENAME", by(year)
```

then it computes the numbers that it's supposed to compute.

This is a panel dataset, `unit` denotes number within a powerplant of a particular generator unit (units numbered 0 are plant-level observations). The `cap` variable is installed capacity. The `name` variable identifies the plant. It's complicated to explain why I need this loop, but the problem is clearly with the way Stata interprets `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues here.  Most importantly, your first loop is evaluating the word `name` in place of `x` throughout your loop.   So it is running your `egen` command as:

```
foreach x of varlist name {
     egen totalcapname = total(cap) if unit!=0 and name=="name", by(year)
}
```

I doubt this is what you really want--I think you want it to evaluate by each item (observation) in your `name` variable since you used the `if` condition

```
name=="`x'"
```

So, you need to

- get rid of the double quotes around the  macro reference in your `if` condition

OR

- set up a local macro and set the `egen` loop to evaluate for each item in your `name` variable.

The second error I see in your code is that you are missing the forward or left quote for the `x` in the loop--it should read

```
"`x'"`
```

not

```
"x'"
```

Here is an example of what I THINK you want to run.  For illustration purposes, I am using the Stata in-built "auto.dta" dataset to run your loop & standalone `egen` statement...please note that I rename the variables in the auto.dta to the names of your variables:

```
***********
clear
sysuse auto


**
//this section renames the auto.dta variables to the name of your variables//

gen year = [_n]
rename mpg cap
rename price unit
rename make name
**NOTE:  your "SOMENAME" will be "Subaru" in this example!**
**

//here's the loop you should be running//

foreach x of varlist name {
 egen totalcap`x'=total(cap) if unit!=0 & name==`x', by(year) 
 }

//without the loop//

egen totalcapSOMENAME=total(cap) if unit!=0 & name=="Subaru", by(year)

//Display the results//

li name unit cap totalcap* if !missing(totalcapSOMENAME)
***********
```

Try running this example in a Stata do-file.  Also, when you have these sort of issues (where the loop creates a different outcome than the stand alone command), always try typing `set trace on`  so that you can see how Stata is evaluating your loop.

Comment: One thing I forgot to highlight (but is included in the code snippet I provided)--you don't need the double quotes around x in the loop, just single quotes...so it should be ==`x' , not =="x".

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer above was accepted (almost 11 years ago) there is a misunderstanding in the question that is both frequent and deserving of a little more emphasis than in @eric.a.booth's helpful answer.

The misunderstanding is that

```
foreach x of varlist name
```

is somehow automatically a loop over the distinct (some say "unique", but that is not a good term in my view) values of the variable `name`. Other software may do that for you but it's in no sense what Stata promises with `foreach`. That is a loop over precisely one item, the single variable name in the supplied *varlist*. As such it's overkill as you could just type the statement(s) inside the loop, but Stata naturally doesn't forbid a *varlist* with just one name or using such in `foreach`.

In this particular case,

```
egen totalcap = total(cap) if unit!=0, by(name year)
```

would put all the totals of interest in a single variable and if you preferred that to go in several variables, then use `separate` to do that without a loop (or more precisely, `separate` uses a loop, but it is within the code).